# How To Open App From Link And not play store - Android

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to check if app is installed then open app and if not then play store. I tried using my app's play store link but did not work

```js
   <intent-filter
        android:autoVerify="true"
        android:label="Notification Log">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            
            android:host="play.google.com"
            android:path="/store/apps/details?id=com.appnotification.notificationhistorylog"
            android:scheme="http" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Can anyone help me with this

Answer (score 0):

Updated

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

    <data
        android:host="www.this-so-does-not-exist.com"
        android:path="/something"
        android:scheme="http"
        android:pathPattern="/.*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Then, links to http://www.this-so-does-not-exist.com/something will bring up your app (in a chooser, along with the Web browse) on devices that have your app, and will bring up your Web page on devices that do not have your app.

Comment: but will this work when I want to open my own app

Comment: Above code will place in your app to check either app whose package id you are using is installed or not. If installed then it will open the app and if not then it will open it on PlayStore

Comment: but what if the above app itself is not installed

Comment: what i am saying that - My App Name Is "A" and I have put playstore link on  my website for "A", If app is installed open app and not then goto playstore

Comment: You want to navigate from website?

Comment: yes, through play store link

Comment: i did it by changing into bit.ly url

Comment: Try adding **android:pathPattern** to the intent filter. I have updated

Answer (score 0):

It worked by changing Playstore link to short Url

```js
   <data

            android:host="bit.ly"
            android:path="/yourappname"
            android:scheme="http" />
```

Comment: This works but you can't get the data from the deeplink (long url). Did you manage to do that? e.g. if you are passing parameters